# Unity emission lighting

Tags: unity, lighting

I have created a scene with a blue sphere inside of a white room of planes. The room is being lit by a point light above the roof, and the sphere is emitting a blue light.

[image: The room and sphere]

How do I get the emission from the sphere to contribute to the lighting of the walls without making it static?

Comment: All dynamic lighting is handled through the various Light components. Have you tried adding a light to it?

Comment: @DMGregory The only light component that I have in the scene is a point light, and the sphere's material is emitting light. Is there a setting on either of these I need to adjust?

Comment: An "emissive" material does not mean it's dynamically shining light on its surroundings. It just means it can brighten itself up, glowing through its own surface shading. For static light baking, this makes the surface brighter which gets picked up by the bounce light simulation, so you might see some transport on adjacent surfaces. For dynamic lighting effects, you need a light component to shine the light onto nearby objects.